# Generalized function to avoid repeatativeness

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, kotlin-coroutines

I want to have a generalized function for my repository method that makes an API call. Here is the code -

RemoteInterface.java

```
interface RemoteInterface {

    @GET("...")
    suspend fun getRandomImage(): MyModel

    @GET(".../{id}/...")
    suspend fun getRandomImageById(@Path("id") id: String): MyModel
}
```

Now my Repositoryclass looks like this -

```
override suspend fun getImageFromRemote(): MyResult {
        if (util.checkDeviceInternet()) {
            try {
                val result = remoteInterface.getRandomImage()
                if (result.status == "200") {
                    return MyResult.Content(result)
                } else {
                    return MyResult.Error(MyResult.ErrorType.API_ERROR)
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                return MyResult.Error(MyResult.ErrorType.API_ERROR)
            }
        } else {
            return MyResult.Error(MyResult.ErrorType.NO_INTERNET)
        }
    }

    override suspend fun getImageByIdFromRemote(id: String): MyResult {
        if (util.checkDeviceInternet()) {
            try {
                val result = remoteInterface.getRandomImageById(id)
                if (result.status == "200") {
                    return MyResult.Content(result)
                } else {
                    return MyResult.Error(MyResult.ErrorType.API_ERROR)
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                return MyResult.Error(MyResult.ErrorType.API_ERROR)
            }
        } else {
            return MyResult.Error(MyResult.ErrorType.NO_INTERNET)
        }
    }
```

As you see, my 2 methods in Repository have repetitive function body. Is there any way I could write a generalized function that does the same functionality as these 2 function?

Comment: you must use the `method overloading` technique to achieve that, see here: https://medium.com/coding-blocks/leveraging-the-power-of-functions-in-kotlin-de5fd9db065a

Comment: This is not how you implement retrofit.

Comment: @KaushikBurkule Could you pls explain my mistake? Would be helpful

Comment: let me confirm that are you using retrofit lib for network calls?

Comment: Yes I do...I m using 2.6.1 version

Comment: Retrofit 2.6.0 has been released with support for suspend functions. So you are doing it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an inline function to do this, with zero overhead.

```
private inline fun usefulFunction(block: () -> MyModel): MyResult {
    if (util.checkDeviceInternet()) {
        try {
            val result = block()
            if (result.status == "200") {
                return MyResult.Content(result)
            } else {
                return MyResult.Error(MyResult.ErrorType.API_ERROR)
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            return MyResult.Error(MyResult.ErrorType.API_ERROR)
        }
    } else {
        return MyResult.Error(MyResult.ErrorType.NO_INTERNET)
    }
}
```

then in your repository functions, you can do.

```
override suspend fun getImageFromRemote(): MyResult {
    return usefulFunction {
        remoteInterface.getRandomImage()
    } 
}

override suspend fun getImageByIdFromRemote(id: String): MyResult {
    return usefulFunction {
        remoteInterface.getRandomImageById(id)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `try{}catch{}` block and replace it with a `CoroutineExceptionHandler`:

```
val coroutineExceptionHandler = CoroutineExceptionHandler{_,_ -> return MyResult.Error(MyResult.ErrorType.API_ERROR)
}

coroutineScope.launch(coroutineExceptionHandler ){
  val result = getImageFromRemote()
}
```